# Connect to ADLS gen 1 with Azure Databricks using SPN + certificate

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-data-lake, spn

I want to connect to a datalake store in databricks using a service principal with certificate(pfx or pem). On the databricks page there is only reference to using access tokens.

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake.html

Is it possible to use a certificate?

Comment: are you on AWS or Azure Databricks?

Comment: I am on  -  Azure